# Read Lock on a row of a Database table

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, cron, locking

I am trying to build a job scheduler.I have a list of jobs to be executed on 2-3 different machines on time basis. So any machine can pick any job and will execute it if its `next_execution_time < current_time`. I am storing all the jobs in a database table and I am using `SELECT.... FOR UPDATE` query in SQL to select a job for execution.

But the problem with this approach is that, if a machine1 has picked a job, since there is only write lock, other machines will also select the same job for for execution, but can't execute as they will wait for the lock to be released or lock timeout will occur. So is there any way so that other machine skips this job and execute other jobs using SQL locks. No other column should be added in the database?

Flow is something like this :

```
select a job and lock it -> execute the job -> release the lock
```

I am using ruby-on-rails for developing this. If there is no-wait or set_lock_timeout = 0 in rails. it can probably solve the problem. If there exists ... what is the syntax?

Comment: You can set a flag to the rows being processed, such as `being_processed="Y"` and filter rows by `being_processed!="Y"`.

Comment: @fedorqui yes,i was using an extra column "locked_by" = machine_ip to check whether the the job is locked/executing or not, but this is not recommended, because if a machine goes down while executing a task, the lock will never be released.

Comment: Yes, you are right. You could also use `redis` for this and set a flag that expires after a certain amount of time.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you have a simple way of doing this with your current table in mysql, you need to temporarily lock the table when selecting the next task. I'm assuming you have a column in the table to flag already started/done tasks, otherwise you can use the same column with the datetime to start the job to flag that it is already done/started:

```
lock tables jobs write;

select * from jobs where start_time < current_time and status = 'pending' order by start_time;
-- be carefull here to check for SQL errors in your code and run unlock tables if an exception is thrown or something like that

update jobs set status = 'started' where id = the_one_you_selected_adobe;

unlock tables;
```

And that's it, multiple concurrent threads/processes cab use the jobs table to execute tasks without having 2 threads running the same task.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I have been using the same approach, but again the problem is if a machine goes down while executing a task, the status will never be changed and this job will never be executed as the status will always be started. So i was asking is there any locking technique internally at sql server level, which will take care of this locking mechanism on its own.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, yes there is such a mechanism, it is called Transaction. The specific implementation may differ depending on the engine you use (I assume you are using MySQL for the tags on the question) but innoDB def has support for transactions. The idea is the same, you need to read (select) the next task from the table and update the status of the task to 'started' or something like that inside a transaction and the DBMS will take care of the rest.